# MySQL search without any special characters

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering if it's possible to search through a MySQL field where the field may have something like this:

```
test - hello
```

but you have in a string from a user

```
test: hello
```

Obviously it's easy on PHP-side to strip the string of any special characters like that, but is it possible to search through MySQL rows and ignore special characters?

Comment: use a fulltext index, basically. otherwise, no, you can't "ignore" characters. that's something your code has to do, not mysql.

Answer (score 4):

Another unique solution is to put wildcards in between each word. As long as the search phrase does not have special characters in it, the correct results will be returned while ignoring any special characters in the results.

For example...

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE somefield LIKE '%test%hello%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible if you find and replace all such special character and spaces from user input also  column,
i.e.

```
select * from tablename where replace(replace(columnname,' ',''),':',''),'-','')=replace(replace([USER INPUT],' ',''),':',''),'-','');
```

Comment: Hmmm that's quite a novel approach, might give it a go, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of "ignore" special characters, whitespace, etc. by using the `SOUNDEX()` function:

```
mysql> select soundex('test - hello'), soundex('test: hello');
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| soundex('test - hello') | soundex('test: hello') |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| T234                    | T234                   |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

So you can search your data like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE SOUNDEX(somefield) = SOUNDEX('test: hello');
```

This won't be indexable at all, so it'll be forced to do a table-scan. If you use MySQL 5.7, you could add a virtual column for the soundex expression, and index that virtual column. That would help performance a lot.

Comment: **People without the knowledge on `SOUNDEX`, BEWARE!** @BillKarwin Please add a `warning` at the top of your answer stating that different spellings can also have same `soundex code`. For instance, try `SELECT SOUNDEX('hello - world'), SOUNDEX('helo - world'), SOUNDEX('helllo : world'), SOUNDEX('hello : worrld')`. BTW, your answer is wrong in general (but may work for OP) for the very same reason; it may return incorrect records that sound similar

Comment: Yes, of course one should know how the function works before using it. The OP had a requirement to do a certain type of inexact matching.